# Who's missing from the Imperial Military Council meeting?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, rogue-one

In *A New Hope*, there is this council of random Imperials in the "I find your lack of faith disturbing" scene. They are called the Joint Chiefs. However, there is one empty chair on the council.

[image]

I suspect it belongs to Orson Krennic, who

> is fired (upon by the Death Star).

**Has it been revealed in the canon who's missing?**

Comment: Any pictures perchance?

Comment: All the pictures are too big.

Comment: You can adjust size by appending the letters s,m,l (small, medium, large) to the imgur link created when you upload an image. Or if you mean file size, you can take a screenshot and save as jpeg.

Comment: Negative. Orson was NOT Joint Chief, he was a Director of a program. Basically, high level bureaucrat. But NOT in the military or government power.

Comment: Could it not be for Darth Vader?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The vacant seat was Krennic's, according to the (canon) short story [Fully Operational](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fully_Operational_(short_story)). The Director was unable to attend due to slight case of deadness.

> *Krennic had shoved his chair aside, standing up and beating a fist on
> the table. Tagge, two seats down, had both admired the man’s passion
> for the battle station and been disgusted by the childish way in which
> he presented it.*
>
> *In the end, Krennic got what he’d wanted. Another test fire, a larger
> one. **Now the seat two chairs down from Tagge’s was empty.***
>
> <sub><sup>[From a Certain Point of View](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View): [Fully Operational](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Fully_Operational_(short_story))</sup></sub>